# A multivariable limit question (differentiability of exponential)

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am trying to show that the function $e^{x+y}$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ by using formal definition. Hence, I need to show $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{e^{x+y}-1-x-y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0$$.

I tried to use Squeeze Theorem but I could not get the result.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By letting $\;z=x+y\,,\,$ we get that

$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{e^{x+y}-1-(x+y)}{(x+y)^2}=\lim\limits_{z\to0}\dfrac{e^z-1-z}{z^2}=\dfrac12\,.$

Since for any $\;(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\;\land\;(x,y)\neq(0,0)\;$ it results that

$0\leqslant\dfrac{(x+y)^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\leqslant\dfrac{2\left(x^2+y^2\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\;\;,$

by applying Squeeze Theorem, we get that

$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{(x+y)^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0\,.$

Consequently ,

$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{e^{x+y}-1-x-y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=$

$=\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{e^{x+y}-1-(x+y)}{(x+y)^2}\cdot\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{(x+y)^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=$

$=\dfrac12\cdot0=0\;.$